# How to connect to a linux server that's based in China?

Tags: php, linux, apache-2.2

it's as the title states. How do I connect/access my web/database sever that's located in China.

OS: RedHat 6.0

Websever: Apache 2.2

Database: MySQL 5.1

Server Scripting Language: PHP 5.3

for starters, i've tried pinging the ip address of both the web sever and the database server.
100% sent, 100% loss.

I've heard that it might be due to the firewall of China's, but i'm not sure.
anyone have any ideas? please share~ thanks :)

did a tracert.. 20 hops.. & it doesn't look that bad..

```
1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  menu <my ip address>
2    11 ms     9 ms     9 ms  bb116-14-180-1.singnet.com.sg [116.14.180.1]
3    92 ms     9 ms     9 ms  202.166.121.41
4     9 ms     9 ms     9 ms  xe-7-1-0-3700.sherry.singnet.com.sg [202.166.124.105]
5    10 ms    11 ms    68 ms  ae9-0.budweiser.singnet.com.sg [202.166.126.238]
6    52 ms    15 ms     9 ms  ae6-0.pepsi.singnet.com.sg [202.166.126.97]
7    11 ms    11 ms    11 ms  203.208.191.42
8    10 ms    11 ms    11 ms  203.208.152.205
9   181 ms   192 ms   188 ms  203.208.153.162
10   234 ms   202 ms   230 ms  ge-3-1-0-0.sngc3-ar4.ix.singtel.com [203.208.152.110]
11   196 ms   190 ms   204 ms  67.17.192.141
12   184 ms   196 ms   192 ms  218.30.54.113
13   181 ms   198 ms   182 ms  202.97.52.225
14   436 ms   440 ms   444 ms  202.97.51.13
15   470 ms   441 ms   425 ms  202.97.60.205
16   452 ms   442 ms   444 ms  202.97.35.197
17   452 ms   484 ms   478 ms  183.59.1.5
18   443 ms   468 ms   451 ms  183.59.1.137
19     *      474 ms   474 ms  61.142.101.186
20   486 ms   462 ms   454 ms  <server ip address>

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Did you ask the sysadmin of the Chinese server?

Comment: apparently, they don't have anyone technical on their side. they only know how to help install the software for the servers. so, if i  do ask the China side, i'll need to know what to ask and all..

Comment: Try doing a `traceroute` to the IP to see if you can fully "walk" the path to the server from your connection. Furthermore, this is not really a StackOverflow question as it has nothing to do with programming. Voted to move to superuser.com

Comment: What happens when you try to ssh into it?

Comment: @Oldskool i've tried the tracert, results are above.. and i was directed here by a friend of mine.. haha

Comment: @fatfrog only my ftp works. :\atfrog i've tried telnet and ssh as well, connection time out.

Comment: Your FTP works but SSH times out. Have you considered that there is nothing wrong with the connection, and that the problem might be that there is no SSH service running or exposed on the server? We can't help with that, at all.

Comment: Since you have no problem tracing your route all the way to the server there is probably no problem with you connection to the server but with the server itself. How are you trying to connect to it?

Comment: ...use nmap on the IP to see what services show up. You're seeing something at that IP, so if nmap doesn't show the services running they're either firewalled or it's not running (or it's on a nonstandard port).

Answer (score 1):

Ask them how you are supposed to access the system. Ask them if SSH is supported, and if so on what port.

Answer (score -1):

If the SSH connection times out it sounds like a firewall is blocking port 22. You could try this:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php

Comment: Given that any SSH client can use whatever port you want I really can't imagine any reason to suggest something as convoluted as a PHP module for this. That just throws yet another layer into the mix, making it even harder to find the problem.